# Why is Hashkiveinu different?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, chazzan-prayer-leader, amen

Normally, if me and my good friend Shimon complete (finish) a Bracha at the same time, I may not say Amen after his bracha.

However, if I recall correctly, an exception to this is made by the bracha of Haskivenu said by Maariv (the 2nd bracha after Shema). There I should say Amen to the Chazzan's recitation of "Shomer Amoi Yisrael La'ad" regardless of whether I also completed it at the same time.

Why is this so? What is so special about this Bracha that it deviates from the norm?

Answer (score 8):

It's not unique. It's because it's the last blessing in a series. The same is true for *bone (b'rachamav) Y'rushalayim* after a meal and the final *b'racha* of *Halel* and *p'suke d'zimra*.

Specifically, *SA OC* 215:1 has that we say *amen* to our own *b'racha* in each of these cases even *without* hearing someone else simultaneously, and I believe *S'faradim* follow this rule. *Rama* there limits that rule to *bone Y'rushalayim*.

Now, *Rama* there does not discuss the case of finishing the other *b'rachos* — *Hashkivenu* et al. — simultaneously with another's *b'racha*.

However, *Aruch Hashulchan* :4 notes that the *Rama*'s limiting to *bone Y'rushalayim* is because that that's the only *b'racha* on which one *must* answer *amen* to his own (so as to differentiate the *d'oraysa* three *b'rachos* from the fourth): we don't answer *amen* to our own *Hashkivenu* et al. (where it's permitted but not required to do so) so as to lend more oomph to the differentiation afforded by answering *bone*.

This *AHS* supplies us, perhaps, with the reason answering one's own *bone Y'rushalayim* (and the others) is appropriate when hearing another's *b'racha* simultaneously. Since there's really nothing wrong with doing so (as there usually is when finishing a *b'racha* oneself), it's appropriate when one's heard someone else's *b'racha*.

As to why the last blessing in a series has the you-may-answer-your-own rule, I don't know.

Comment: We say Amen after _bone (b'rachamav) Y'rushalayim_ to differentiate between the first 3 blessings which are biblical and the 4 blessing which is rabinical: Shulchan Aruch HaRav 188:1 (see footnotes for sources - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&pgnum=556)

Comment: @Menachem, that's why _Ashk'nazim_ do it, yes. But that's not why we say "_amen_" to it when finishing at the same time as another, which is what the question asked: for that _halacha_, it's no different from _Hashkivenu_ and the end of _Halel_ and _p'suke d'zimra_.

Comment: Boneh Yerushalayim has a specific requirement that the Hazan himself says Amen at the end of the Berachah, to split the different types of Berachoth, as @Menachem said.

Comment: @SethJ, yes, but without that special _halacha_ the _b'racha_ would still have the rule, as _Hashkivenu_ et al. do, that you answer another's who finishes with you.

Comment: Now you're using Hashkiveinu to demonstrate the rule as it applies to Boneh Yerushalayim, which was your choice to demonstrate the rule as applied to the Berachah in the question (Hashkiveinu)! This seems like circular logic. Am I missing something? I see that you have other examples, but Boneh Yerushalayim is the most obvious and recognized - the problem is that it is both obvious and widely recognized for an entirely different reason.

Comment: I can't look up the Shu"'A now; does he (or anyone else there) state the reason you mentioned (that it is the last in a series)?

Comment: @SethJ, I didn't mean that the existence of the same _halacha_ for _Hashkivenu_ as I claimed exists for _Bone_ proves that it exists for _Bone_. I claim it does, and that's all. `:-)` ¶ Yes, _SA_ gives that reason. But I see now that I misattributed some stuff to him, so will fix my answer.

Comment: A) it's verachamav with no dagesh in the bet. B) Another example of brachot that end a series is ga'al yisrael by shacharit. that is why some don't think the custom of ending the bracha with the chazzan solves the amen issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA, with a _ves_ makes more sense to me, but I've seen it both ways.